# Question on Erickson 'momselect' algorithm

Tags: sorting, recursion

In the Erickson Algorithms textbook (file:///C:/Users/G068078/OneDrive%20-%20Kaiser%20Permanente/Algorithms_Technique_and_Theory_CS_388G/Undergraduate_CS331/Algorithms-JeffE.pdf)
it has pseudocode for 'momselect':
[image]

This is probably a really basic question but I do not get how it ever gets past the red part.  It recurses to eventually find the "median of medians" (mom), but once it gets below 25, it simply used brute force.  How does it ever reach the "Partition" step?

Comment: I encourage you to fix the link to the textbook.

Answer (score 2):

In the pseudocode "use brute force" means "compute the median of the input sequence (with any algorithm) and **return it** (to the caller)".

Eventually all the children calls in the recursion tree starting at the red call to "MomSelect" will terminate and the control will return to the current execution of the algorithm, that will move to the next (black) instruction.